# Can't run JApplet - Impossible to load library for security problems

Tags: java, applet, digital-signature

from days i'm trying to reach to launch [that project](https://github.com/provinciaditreviso/javafirma).

Is a java project to create a digital signature of a file.

what i've done from centos distribution ( 64bit ) is:

1. create certificate using

   keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias ALIAS -keystore sign_javafirma.keystore -storepass PASSWORD -validity 365 -keysize 2048
2. edit buildjar.xml changing ALIAS and PASSWORD with the one selected on point 1.
3. install icedtea-web (yum install icedtea-web)
4. make //it will launch ant to generate jar.

After that jar is correctly generated and signed, i try applet with this html:

```
<applet code="it.treviso.provincia.freesigner.applet.FreeSignerSignApplet" type="application/x-java-applet" width="500" height="200">
        <param name="archive" value="freesignerapplet.jar" />
        <!-- file to sign. Result will be on the same directory -->
        <param name="filename" value="test.pdf" />
        <!-- path of the library of the card reader -->
        <param name="devlib" value="x64/libbit4ipki.so" />
        <!-- url called after the completion of the sign, passing the hash of the document as GET parameter -->
        <param name="callback" value="http://pratiche.prov.tv.local/callback.php?key=blablabla" />
      <strong>
    This browser does not have a Java Plug-in.
      </strong>
      <br />
      <a href="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/downloads/index.html">
        Get the latest Java Plug-in here.
      </a>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

where x64/libbit4ipki.so is a library downloaded from [this website](http://www.ordineavvocativenezia.net/CMS/remository/Hi-Tech/Software/Driver-Linux-per-smart-card-Incard/).

When i try to go to the page which has to load applet, after request to launch an insicure applet, i have message: "Impossible to load library for security problems" and in console i don't have nothing.

How can i reach to launch that project?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Did you sign your applet with an official certificate?

Comment: i've tried different versions. from 6 to 8

Comment: Since recently *racle changed a lot of security related stuff. For instance you must sign your applet with an official certificate to be able to run it. If you use an older version try e.g. 7.0.17 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u17-oth-JPR and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is probably here:

> create certificate using
>
> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias ALIAS -keystore sign_javafirma.keystore -storepass PASSWORD -validity 365 -keysize 2048

This certificate is used by ant build buildjar.xml to sign the jar:

```
<signjar destDir="signed" alias="ALIAS" storepass="PASSWORD" keystore="sign_javafirma.keystore">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="." includes="freesignerapplet.jar" />
  </path>
    <flattenmapper />
</signjar>
```

This is a self signed certificate and self signed certification are not ok anymore for signing applets. You need to get a code signing certificate from a trusted source (ie verisign, Thawte, Entrust, etc).